# mysql query from 2 tables with conditions

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have 2 tables

orderitems

`+--------+------------+------------------+---------+
| item_id| item_name  |  Item_type       |   trans |
+--------+------------+------------------+---------+
| 1      | Devon      | line_item        | 0       |
| 2      | 100        | coupon           | 0       |
| 3      | Contin     | line_item        | 1       |
+--------+------------+------------------+---------+`

orderitems_data

`1+--------+------------+------------------+-----------+
|   id   | item_id    |  Item_key        | key_val    |
+--------+------------+------------------+------------+
| 1      | 1          | Delivery         | 2015/04/03 |
| 2      | 1          | attrib           | pick_up    |
| 3      | 1          | qty              | 1          |
| 4      | 2          | discount         | 0          |
| 5      | 3          | Delivery         | 2015/04/15 |
| 5      | 3          | attrib           | doorstep   |
+--------+------------+------------------+------------+`

I need to select the 'item_name' from 'orderitems' where the 'Item_type = line_item' and 'trans=0', the 'key_val' from 'orderitems_data' where 'Item_key = Delivery', and the 'key_val' where 'Item_key=attribute' for the same 'item_name'

Then display them. I am struggling with the query, I want to write

```
 SELECT orderitems.item_name AS item_name WHERE orderitems.Item_type='line_item' AND trans=0, orderitems_data.key_val AS deliverydate WHERE Item_key='Delivery', orderitems_data.key_val AS location WHERE Item_key='attrib' FROM orderitems INNER JOIN order_items_data ON orderitems.item_id = orderitems_data.item_id
```

But clearly it isnt right.

Could someone point me in the correct direction please?

The result I'm looking to get is

```
Devon pick_up 2015/04/03
```

Comment: Can you give the create table command so that we can have a try.

Comment: Note that id in your orderitems_data table is redundant. Also, when using an EAV model such as this, try to make sure that you are still respecting data types where possible.

Comment: Can you please provide the desired result.

Comment: This is all great info thanks, @Strawberry I didn't design the DB but I will look at your comments. The result I am looking for is to select Devon pick_up 2015/04/03 thanks again

Comment: Please update your question with any additional information.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you -

```
SELECT orderitems.item_name AS item_name, orderitems_data.key_val AS deliverydate, orderitems_data.key_val AS location from orderitems left join orderitems_data
ON orderitems.item_id = orderitems_data.item_id
WHERE orderitems.Item_type='line_item' AND 
    orderitems.trans=0  and 
    ( orderitems_data.Item_key='Delivery' or orderitems_data.Item_key='attrib')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT oi.item_name, oid.key_val
FROM OrderItem oi, Orderitem_Data oid
WHERE oi.item_id = od.item_id
AND oi.item_type = 'line_item'
AND oid.item_key = 'Delivery'
```

Didn't get what you were asking in the end

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will work

```
SELECT i.item_name, d.Item_key FROM orderitems i LEFT JOIN orderitems_data d on i.item_id =d.item_id WHERE i.Item_type='line_item' AND i.trans=0 AND d.Item_key in('attrib', 'Delivery');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a stock answer for constructing a pseudo-normalised pivot from an EAV data set:

```
SELECT i.*
     , MAX(CASE WHEN d.item_key = 'attrib' THEN key_val END) attrib
     , MAX(CASE WHEN d.item_key = 'Delivery' THEN key_val END) Delivery
     , MAX(CASE WHEN d.item_key = 'qty' THEN key_val END) qty
     , MAX(CASE WHEN d.item_key = 'discount' THEN key_val END) discount
  FROM orderitems i 
  LEFT 
  JOIN orderitems_data d 
    ON d.item_id = i.item_id 
 GROUP 
    BY i.item_id;
+---------+-----------+-----------+-------+----------+------------+------+----------+
| item_id | item_name | Item_type | trans | attrib   | Delivery   | qty  | discount |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-------+----------+------------+------+----------+
|       1 | Devon     | line_item |     0 | pick_up  | 2015/04/03 | 1    | NULL     |
|       2 | 100       | coupon    |     0 | NULL     | NULL       | NULL | 0        |
|       3 | Contin    | line_item |     1 | doorstep | 2015/04/15 | NULL | NULL     |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-------+----------+------------+------+----------+
```

Note my previous comments concerning the redundancy of the id column in the orderitems_data table and the importance of using proper data types where possible.

Answer (score 0):

If, I am not wrong you want to get the depends on `Item_type = 'line_item'` and `trans = 0` and `od.Item_key = 'Delivery' OR  od.Item_key = 'attrib'` then use below query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  o.*,
  od.key_val,
  od.Item_key
FROM
  orderitems o
  LEFT JOIN orderitems_data od
    ON o.item_id = od.item_id 
WHERE o.Item_type = 'line_item' 
  AND o.trans = 0 
  AND (od.Item_key = 'Delivery' OR  od.Item_key = 'attrib')
```